# How to google image search from excel cell content and return url?

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to write a macro or vba which will image search the cell content in row A and return the image's url? Ive been able to return the first result in the past or the first search result but i can't figure out how to make one that will return a relevant image such as:

http://www.gamexchange.co.uk/images/pictures/products/ps3/littlebigplanet-3-ps3-(product-photography).jpg?v=b13dfc3644d28cd2cff7d5729a35fc5e

Any help would be appreciated, as i think i've exhausted the search function now.

Thank you.

[image]

Here is the code I've used which doesn't work as desired.

```
 Sub XMLHTTP()

Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
Dim start_time As Date
Dim end_time As Date

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim cookie As String
Dim result_cookie As String

start_time = Time
Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

For i = 2 To lastRow

    url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
    XMLHTTP.send

        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
    Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")
    Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname("H3")(0)
    Set link = objH3.getelementsbytagname("a")(0)


    str_text = Replace(link.innerHTML, "<EM>", "")
    str_text = Replace(str_text, "</EM>", "")

    Cells(i, 2) = str_text
    Cells(i, 3) = link.href
    DoEvents
Next

end_time = Time
Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just this code which loops through the text strings in column a, performs a google search on each string
and saves the title and url of the first result to the corresponding cells in columns b and c.

it won't let me post the code here as its too long but it was difficult for me to implement and still doesn't do what i need it to do.

Comment: please consider posting a [short, self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) of your code. If you're asking others to reinvent the wheel for you, you're unlikely to get much assistance.

Comment: **DO NOT PUT CODE IN THE COMMENTS**.  Revise your question to include the code. It is **impossible** to read in the comments.

Comment: Apologies, hopefully this is correct

Comment: much better. I'll take a look and see if I can help :)

Comment: OK so for the first handle, you would want to return an image from the resulting link: http://www.amazon.co.uk/pqube-Fallen-Earth-PC-CD/dp/B004CYE4NE ?

Comment: Yes, thats the exact type of image i would like to return.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that every search is going to take you to a different domain, with a **completely different** HTML structure.

There is no reliable way to do this and bring in the *correct* picture, because you cannot possibly know in advance the structure of the returned HTML which you need to parse for the image... Of course you could try to return, for instance, the **first** image on each page, but since the pages will likely contain *many* images which are irrelevant to your search, that is not going to be very reliable.

One alternative would be to do what you are currently doing to obtain the `str_text` and the `link.href` to columns B and C of your spreadsheet, and then run a **second** XMLHTTP request to a URL of the following structure:

```
url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X" & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)
```

This will return a Google Image search. Again, this will not be perfect since the application has no way of knowing which is the "best" picture to return, but you could more reliably return the *first* image since these results will be more likely relevant to your search term.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying this as i've been working on it for a little while now. Your comment has inspired another thought process for me...

is it possible to skip the google search and instead search for image urls from Gamestop?

http://www.gamexchange.co.uk/images/pictures/products/ps3/littlebigplanet-3-ps3-(product-photography).jpg?v=b13dfc3644d28cd2cff7d5729a35fc5e

Game stop urls are always the same except for the actual name of the photo which is always the name of the product so it should remove the HTML structure issue maybe?

Comment: well sure it is probably possible if you can give it the right search query, but those search queries listed in Column A don't really appear to return much of any results if you do a search on that domain.